# How to create a new table from an existing table with rows of the existing table as the columns of the new table. table

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $sql="SELECT qno FROM `cia1questions` ";
        $result = $mysqli ->query($sql);
        $counter = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $createnew="CREATE table cia1markstest(
            Reg_no INT[12] primary key,
            st_name varchar[50] not null";
            $createnew1="";
        if($counter>0)
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++){
                $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
                $createnew1.",".$row['qno']." INT[3]";

            } 
        }
        $createnew1.")";

        echo $createnew.$createnew1;
        $re=$mysqli->query($createnew.$createnew1);
```

This is failing to create a new table. How can i fix this? When i echo the output sql string only the createnew string is reading. can someone help?

Comment: After removing `[num]` after the int column definations, and changing `[50]` to `(50)` like its syntax demands, show the table definition and the SQL error.

Comment: `if($counter>0)` is redundent as its covered in the `for` loop.

Comment: To append to a string, use `.=`, not `.` on it's own. i.e. `$createnew1.",".$row['qno']." INT[3]";` => `$createnew1.=",".$row['qno']." INT[3]";` and `$createnew1.")";` => `$createnew1.=")";`

Comment: @ShashankR you're still not reading. Recommend obliterating "not working" as a phrased used in any form of technical help forum. Be specific about what response you did get and what you expected.

Comment: Try and be consistent here. `$mysqli->query()` is the object-oriented interface, and that's the one you should use. `mysqli_num_rows()` is the old procedural one that should be avoided because it's easily confused with the legacy `mysql_num_rows()` alternative that's been deleted in PHP 7. If this seems like an unnecessary detail, programming is all about details. Use the wrong brackets, miss a comma, and you'll be stuck debugging. Whenever you're not sure how to do something, [**check the documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html). It will tell you what to do.